# MariaDB 11.1.2 for create a custom column for row number

Tags: mariadb-11

Below two sql was working fine with MariaDB 10.5.8 and MySQL 5.7

```
SET @curRow=0;
select @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number, `users`.`name` from `users`
```

or

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY users.id) AS row_number, `users`.`name` from `users`
```

But when I run in MariaDB 11.1.2
It throws error:
Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'row_number, `users`.`name` from `users`' at line 1

I checked with ChatGPT 3.5
It suggest me

```
SELECT row_number FROM (
SELECT @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number, name
        FROM users, (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
) AS subquery_alias
```

The error you're encountering is because you cannot use a user-defined variable to generate row numbers directly within the SELECT clause and then reference it within the same SELECT clause in MariaDB. Instead, you should use a subquery or a common table expression (CTE) to achieve this. Here's how you can rewrite your query using a subquery.

But it is not working.
So what to do in MariaDB 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for danblack answer it - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/158002/danblack

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/331502/mariadb-11-1-2-for-create-a-custom-column-for-row-number